# JavaScript (Node.js): локальные переменные и замыкания

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, замыкания

### Ситуация

У меня есть *node.js* сервер на *express*. С помощью *socket.io* хочу отправить данные из базы данных *mongodb* на клиент.

```js
const socket = require('socket.io');
const io = socket(server);

//Запускаю сервер и подключаюсь к базе данных
//переменная "db" - база данных

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.info(`Connected: ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.info(`Disconected: ${socket.id}`)
    });
    socket.on('search', data => {
        // верхний уровень
        var results = [];
        db.collection('diseases').find({'ttl.txt': {$regex: data, $options: 'i'}}).forEach(document =>{
            // нижний уровень
            results.push(document.ttl[0].txt);
        });
        io.sockets.emit('search', results);
    });
});
```

### Проблема

На `нижнем уровне` хочу записать в переменную `results`, расположенную на `верхнем уровне` данные. Хотя на нижнем уровне переменная перезаписывается, на верхнем остается без изменений.

### Вопрос

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему. Эта проблема возникает у меня довольно часто, но всегда находил запасной план, но тут не смог. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: возможно я поторопился с дубликатом: метод find - синхронная функция или асинхронная? Если синхронная - то скорее всего она просто возвращает пустой массив, и в forEach даже не заходит, вот почему возвращается пустой results

Comment: Метод find асинхронная функция. Запрос возвращает нужные документы, и если вывести переменную `results` на нижнем уровне в консоль - она покажет то что нужно, но вот на верхнем не переписывается.

Comment: тогда дубликат правильный.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь Вам поможет что-то вроде этого подхода: db.collection('diseases').find({'ttl.txt': {$regex: data, $options: 'i'}}, (err, documents) => {
        io.sockets.emit('search', documents.map((document) => document.ttl[0].txt));
    })